# getting an error as more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression when trying to insert more than one rows in table

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert multiple values into a table from different table in postgresql and encountering an error as [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

```
INSERT INTO coupon (id,entityid)
values
(select nextval('seq_coupon')),(select entityid from card where country in ('China')));
```

This query [select entityid from card where country in ('China'))] has multiple rows.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert rows that come from a SELECT query, don't use the `values` clause. The SELECT query you use for the second column's value returns more than one row which is not permitted in places where a single value is required.

To include a constant value for all newly inserted rows, just add it to the SELECT list of the source query.

```
INSERT INTO coupon (id, entityid, coupon_code)
select nextval('seq_coupon'), entityid, 'A-51'
from card
where country in ('China');
```

---

As a side note: when using `nextval()` there is no need to prefix it with a SELECT, even in the values clause, e.g.

```
insert into coupon (id, entityid) 
values (nextval('some_seq'), ...);
```

Comment: @Niki: Your error is unrelated to the nextval() usage,  - it's caused by the SELECT for the second column's value which returns more than one row (value). But that is not allowed when a single value is expected (as does the `VALUES` clause).

Comment: Thanks for the solution . I have one more confusion like if we have one more column as coupon_code , and the data into that has to be from the coupon table itself then how we can add it??

Comment: can we use the query like INSERT INTO coupon (id,entityid,coupon_code)
select nextval('seq_coupon'), entityid 
from card
where country in ('China'), 'A-51';